# In which scenario do you use chunking instead of full parsing?

Tags: text-mining

Chunking or shallow parsing segments a sentence into a sequence of syntactic constituents or chunks, i.e. sequences of adjacent words grouped on the basis of linguistic properties. It is often referred as efficient and robust approach to parsing natural language and a popular alternative to the full parsing but in which scenario chunking would be the more appropriate technique
over full parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing more than my own personal bias, but if for some reason you only need to detect noun and/or verb phrases, you are often might be better off with chunking. E.g., for document clustering, topic tagging, or simply identifying keywords, NP or VP chunking can be more than sufficient. Also, if you need to work with a language for which no tree-banks exist, you might want to fall back to chunking.

Chunking typically has the advantage of being orders of magnitude faster than deep parsing, but modern (perceptron/neural) parsers are much faster than deep parsers used to be five or ten years ago. However, even to date, deep parsing can choke on long sentences. And, obviously, annotating tree-banks to train a deep parser is more costly than annotating the NP/VP phrases or even just building a rule-based chunker - particularly if you need to detect phrases in non-English texts.